# How to reformat and sort dates stored in nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am trying to display Month and YY part of the date column such that it should appear as

Original Format

```
Apr 12 2009;          
Feb 20 2009;
Dec 24 2008;
May 18 2009;
Jan  8 2009;
Dec  6 2008;
Apr 19 2009;
Jan  4 2009;
May 13 2009;
Jan  5 2009
```

From these dates the day part should be ripped off such that it appears as "Apr 09" and can still be sorted by date such that  it appears as:

```
Dec 08;
Jan 09;
Feb 09;
Mar 09;
Apr 09;
May 09
```

Thanks,
Sag.

Comment: Is the column datatype "date" (SQL 2008) and you've shown the data in US format or an input format? Or is it stored as varchar?

Comment: @gbn, OP is storing them in nvarchar "mon d yyyy"

Comment: Ah yes, "date" would come out differently as "April 23, 2009". Sorry, it's late...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store the dates as strings in the datbase, you need to use a format that builds on the same principle as the ISO-8601 standard, i.e. you use numerical months and place the most significant value first.

To be textually sortable your values would need to look something like:

```
08-12, 09-01, 09-02, 09-03, 09-04, 09-05
```

However, I suggest that you store the dates as datetime values in the database instead, and take care of the formatting when you display the values. That way you can easily sort them in the database (and also do any other processing like getting the difference between two dates).

From a datetime value you can quite easily get the format you want. In .NET for example you use `theDate.ToString("MMM yy")` to format the date exactly as you want it. As you do the formatting after getting the data from the database it's not a problem that the format is not textually sortable.

Comment: I work with a SQL Server database that interacts quite a bit with a mainframe database and dates are always passed back and forth as strings in the format of YYYYMMDD (the only date format it can accept).  This actually works well for sorting and is easy to convert back and forth between other date formats.

Comment: @BBlake: Yes, that format follows the principle to have the most significant value first and use fixed size values, so they are sortable. You can't do much more with them without parsing them though.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177601(SQL.90).aspx) function, and you can sort datetime or smalldatetime in SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 0):

you don't say which database, this is for SQL Server...
try:

```
declare @x table (datestring nvarchar(30))
insert into @x values ('Feb 20 2009')
insert into @x values ('Dec 24 2008')
insert into @x values ('May 18 2009')
insert into @x values ('Jan 8 2009')
insert into @x values ('Dec 6 2008')

select * from @x

SELECT
    LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(30),convert(datetime,datestring),109),3)+' '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(30),convert(datetime,datestring),121),3,2)
    FROM @x
    ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,datestring)
```

**You should not store dates in strings**, it takes more space, and makes it difficult to sort and compare them.